# Custom DialogPreference/ListPreference

Tags: android

In my preferences I have a ListPreference which opens DialogPreference. Now I would like to create a simple dialog without Cancel button and title Category. I want just the list of options, which I would like to make custom too. I already looked at the source code and I'm a bit confused because do I have to write my own dialog preference class just to remove title and cancel button? Or I can just extend DialogPreference to create all the customizations? There are also some widgetLayout/dialogLayout attributes, but I don't see an option how to remove a title/cancel button from there. Or should I extend ListPreference? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, because I'm running out of ideas.
[dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDncB.png)

Answer (score 11):

I managed to solve my problem with title and cancel button. Here is the solution:

```
public class PreferenceDialog extends ListPreference {

public PreferenceDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    builder.setNegativeButton(null,null);
    builder.setTitle(null);
}
```

}

I just had to pass null values and it worked like a charm.